# How to use an LSTM to have an input of 100 timesteps with 128 features and an output of 19000 timesteps with 128 features

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to have an input with 100 timesteps, then use some sort of LSTM cell that outputs 19,000 time steps. Is there any way to do this?

I'm unfamiliar with LSTMs but it seems that in every example I've come across, the output is the same amount of timesteps as the input. I

However, I need the LSTM to output 19000 timesteps, so this will not work. Is there a way to set this up without a ridiculously complicated graph?